# How to retrieve data from Dapper ExecuteReader() and convert it into an int

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper and I want to get all values from a column with a specific condition then convert it to a integer, but I'm unable to access those values.

```
| NumAdultos | NumCrianças |     
|     1      |     0       |    <-----------
|     2      |     1       |    <----------- I want to get all these values;
|     1      |     0       |    <-----------
```

Code:

```
int clienteAlojadoNum = 0;

using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel")))
{
    // How do I convert this value?
    var adultos = connection.ExecuteReader($"SELECT NumAdultos, NumCrianças FROM dbo.Registos WHERE DataEntrada = @DataEntrada and Estado = 'Alojado' ", new { DataEntrada = hoje });

    // I know this is wrong but I don't how to access them or convert them
    clienteAlojadoNum = Convert.ToInt32(adultos);
}
```

Comment: If you're using Dapper you don't need any of that, that's sort of why Dapper exists. Just use [`Query`](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query) and then whatever works best for you -- a tuple, `dynamic` or a custom class.

Comment: Can I store the Query() values in a int variable?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I need to get all those rows values , sum all of them, then convert it to an int variable

Comment: If you need *only* the sum and not the row data it's far better to fold that into the query: `SELECT SUM(NumAdultos + NumCrianças)`. Processing data is what the database server is for, after all! You can then use `.ExecuteScalar` to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Data {
 public int NumAdultos { get; set; }
 public int NumCrianças {get; set; }
}
```

```
int clienteAlojadoNum = 0;
using(IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel"))) {

  var results = connection.Query<Data>($"SELECT NumAdultos, NumCrianças FROM dbo.Registos WHERE DataEntrada = @DataEntrada and Estado = @Estado", new {
    DataEntrada = hoje, 
    Estado = "Alojado"
  });

  clienteAlojadoNum = results.Select(r => r.NumAdultos + r.NumCrianças).Sum();

}
```

Comment: is `r` var `results`?

Comment: `results` is a list returned by the query. r is each element of the list